# Not removing the player cards in deck

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to remove the cards that the player holding in the deck however it only remove the last card in the deck not my desired card that i wanted to remove. Below is my code.I already Update my code.

```
  def remove(self):
    self.cards.pop()
  def game(self):
```

Comment: The method pop() removes and returns last object or obj from the list.

Comment: Please give a [mcve], the code you've posted and the output do not match up. *"it only remove the last card in the deck"* - that's exactly what you've written it to do.

Comment: You never call `remove()` here, where do you call it?

Comment: You are using an instance method to alter global state? Why use OOP at all then? But then, you return the global variable!

Comment: what will i do ? Thank you

Comment: Your code isn't indented correctly (or sufficiently, the style guide calls for four spaces per level).

Comment: I already update my code whenever i use remove it gives me error

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you need:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.remove(2)
>>> print a
[1,3]
```

**EDIT** (based on comment):

In your example it seems you need something like this:

```
>>> a = [[1], [2], [3]]
>>> a.remove([2])
>>> print a
[[1],[3]]
```

Comment: whenever i use remove it gives me an error. The error is self.cards.remove(dealtcards)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: It still giving me an error even i change it to remove([dealtcards])  :(